# Where to store keys of encryption algorithm?

Tags: android, encryption, key

I need to develop an Android application where encryption/decryption is done on client side. The data that is transported and stored in the server MUST be encrypted. The problem is that I cannot store the key of encryption/decryption anywhere.

The keys cannot be stored on the client machine. Because the admins (or someone that can access the server) should not have access to the un-encrypted data.

How to generate keys then? Can you suggest some method?

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question.  Data encryption typically has a public key stored on the user's device, and a private key stored by a remote machine (usually a server).  What exactly are you trying to do that is different from this?

Comment: Who is supposed to be able to read the plaintext? Who is supposed to be able to access the encrypted data only? Who will be encrypting, and who will be decrypting the data? Where does the encrypted data go?

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume that when you say the encryption keys should not be stored in the device, you really mean it :-) Because if that restriction were not there, you could use the [KeyStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html). However, this will mean the keys are stored on the device, which seems not to be what you want.

So, assuming the encryption keys are external to the device, it's somewhat straightforward as there is not much room for choice: your client app asks the user to input the encryption key in some fashion (up to you), which it uses to encrypt the data, and then forgets the encryption key immediately.

Then it sends the encrypted data to the server, where it is stored. The server does not know the encryption keys so to the server it's just an opaque blob of data.

When the user wants to retrieve the data, they have to provide the decryption key on the spot, since it's not stored on the device.

Comment: I can use the KeyStore, however I am generating public and private keys on the device and can't figure out what to use for certificate-- adding a privatekey to the Keystore requires one.  Any idea on this one?